# Where can i find the .cache folder on a linux hosting

Tags: caching, rss

I am trying to add a rss feed into an HTML page. After some searching found something called [simplepie](http://simplepie.org/).

On trying i get an warning

> Warning: ./cache is not writeable.
>   Make sure you've set the correct
>   relative or absolute path, and that
>   the location is server-writable. in
>   xxx/inc/simplepie.inc on line 1780

On checking for the cache folder on the server i couldnt locate the folder. I am on a linux server. Would creating a cache folder be enough or do i need to get the hosting company to look into it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In addition to creating the folder, you will need to make it writable by the user that the script will run as.  You may need the hosting company's help on this.  Otherwise, you can make it world-writable, though if you can restrict it to just allow the user the script runs as, then that would be best.